# SonarCube C# Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false'; some subsequent code is never executed

Tags: c#, if-statement, sonarqube

Sonar Qube raising "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false'; some subsequent code is never executed." for `if (isZeroRulePassed & isAllRulesPassed)` condition.
What's wrong with this code?

```
var isZeroRulePassed = results.All(x => !x.Result);
var isAllRulesPassed = false;
    if (isZeroRulePassed)
    {
        switch (isSubrogation)
        {
            case true when Sum < 500000:
                SimpleRulesSet.ForEach(x =>
                results.Add((RuleResult)x.DynamicInvoke()));
                isAllRulesPassed = results.All(x => !x.Result);
                break;
            case false when Sum < 50000:
                FullRulesSet.ForEach(
                    x => results.Add((RuleResult)x.DynamicInvoke()));
                isAllRulesPassed = results.All(x => !x.Result);
                break;
        }
    }
if (isZeroRulePassed & isAllRulesPassed)
{// Some code}
```

Comment: (true or false) & false == false always, so doesn't matter whether isZeroRulePassed  is true or false, did you mean to use && ?

Comment: yes, I meant using && instead of &